# Spanning of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose we have $\beta^\prime=\{\cosh x,\sinh x\}$ and we want to show that this spans the solution vector space of some ODE given by $V=\{e^x,e^{-x}\}$ provided that we know the ODE whose solutions are in $V$, would it be valid to conclude that if the values in $\beta^\prime$ also satisfy the ODE then $\beta^\prime$ spans $V$?

Comment: elements of $\{\cosh x, 2\cosh x \}$ may satisfy the ODE but not span $V$

Comment: Hint: write $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ in terms of $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution space is the set of functions that can be expressed as $Ae^{t} + Be^{-t}$

$Ae^{t} + Be^{-t} = (A+B)\cosh t + (A-B)\sinh t$

Every function in the solution space can be expressed as a vector in the alternate basis.

Comment: Should the solution instead be $Ae^t+Be^{-t}=(A+B)\cosh{(t)}+(A-B)\sinh{(t)}$? Because the exponential form involves the divide 2? But can you come up with such linear combinations? Is it mostly guessing and checking? @Doug M

Comment: For any pair $(A,B)$ in the basis $\{e^t, e^{-t}\}$ we have found a corresponding pair in the basis $\{\cosh t, \sinh t\}.$  This means that this alternate basis spans the space.